How can I model FM antenna in SPICE?
I'm going to build an FM transmitter.  Should I use 2 pF capacitor in series with 50 Ω resistor (C5 and R3) to represent it?


Modeling an antenna purely with spice is not exactly possible to my knowledge.
You can use a third party software (MMANA-gal software: http://gal-ana.de/basicmm/en/) to model your antenna and from there you can use the parameters that the Software spits out.
You can use this tutorial to help you guide.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RQX3B9jUzWk
Good luck.

hey if you find the answer suitable, you can approve it as the answer to the question.
